# What is this error when pushing Rails App to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, bootstrap-5

It has been some time now that I cannot figure out this error, I am receiving when pushing it to the Heroku.

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss
remote:        Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
remote:        ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
remote:        ParserError: Syntax Error at line: 1, column 25
```

Full error message: https://gist.github.com/zilton7/bbac886c75523aab75bc3561ec22ed55

I have tried many variations for application.scss, but once I have bootstrap uncommented I get the said issue.

application.scss

```
// @import "~bootswatch/dist/darkly/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
// @import "~bootswatch/dist/darkly/bootswatch";

// @import "trix/dist/trix";

// @import "custom"
```

Comment: Think the ~ is unnecessary. Have you tried `@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`

Comment: just tried it, doesn't seem to do anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same issue while deploying my rails application on Heroku. I resolve this by changing bootstrap version in package.json file

from :

[image]

To:

[image]

Source : https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/3188

Comment: Just wanted to add, I had this issue after doing a few related upgrades simultaneously and had to backtrace it. Went from 5.0 to 5.2, and then had to go back to 5.1.2 to get it to work again. Odd, but it's working now I guess.